# comparing int values in android

Tags: android, numbers, int

I am making an android game that is checking the players health value when this method is being runned. But however, it's not reacting. It doesn't do anything, when the value is less than 3, it shouldn't do anything, but when it is equal to 3, it should run a method. Please help me and thanks SO much in advance! This is the code that i am using:

```
        private void checkLivesLeftValue() {
        if (livesLeftValue == 3) {
            //Message to display: "You lost!
            onMethod();
        }
        else {
            livesLeftValue = livesLeftValue + 1;
        }
    }
```

Full code:

```
package com.mysoftwaremobileapps.ParachuteHunter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExampleView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
class ExampleThread extends Thread
{
    private ArrayList<Parachuter> parachuters;
    private Bitmap parachuter;
    private Paint black;

    private boolean running;

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Context mContext;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private GameScreenActivity mActivity;

    private long frameRate;
    private boolean loading;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public MediaPlayer mp1;
    public int parachuterIndexToResetAndDelete;
    public int canvasGetWidth;
    public int livesLeftValue;

    public ExampleThread(SurfaceHolder sHolder, Context context, Handler handler)
    {
        mSurfaceHolder = sHolder;
        mHandler = handler;
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = (GameScreenActivity) context;

        parachuters = new ArrayList<Parachuter>();
        parachuter = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.parachuteman);
        black = new Paint();
        black.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        black.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        running = true;

        // This equates to 26 frames per second.
        frameRate = (long) (1000 / 26);
        loading = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            Canvas c = null;
            try
            {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
                {
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    doDraw(c);
                    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

                    if (diff < frameRate)
                        Thread.sleep(frameRate - diff);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (c != null)
                {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void doDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), black);
        canvasGetWidth = canvas.getWidth();

        //Draw
        for (int i = 0; i < parachuters.size(); i++)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(parachuter, parachuters.get(i).getX(), parachuters.get(i).getY(), null);
            parachuters.get(i).tick();
        }

        //Remove
        for (int i = 0; i < parachuters.size(); i++)
        {
        if (parachuters.get(i).getY() > canvas.getHeight()) {
            parachuters.remove(i);
            onPlaySound();
            checkLivesLeftValue();
        }
    }
    }


    public void onPlaySound()
    {
        try {
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.bombsound);
        mp1.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mp1.release();
        }
    }

    public void onMethod() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You lost!", 15).show();
            }
        });
    } 

    private void checkLivesLeftValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (livesLeftValue == 3) {
            //Message to display: "You lost!
            onMethod();
        }
        else {
            livesLeftValue = livesLeftValue + 1;
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return false;
        float x1 = event.getX();
        float y1 = event.getY();

        initiateDrawParachuters();

        return true;
    }

    public void initiateDrawParachuters()
    {
        drawParachuter1();
    }

    private void drawParachuter1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 1
        x = 68;
        y = 40;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter2();
    }

    private void drawParachuter2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 2
        x = 100;
        y = 80;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter3();
    }

    private void drawParachuter3() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 3
        x = 150;
        y = 120;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter4();
    }

    private void drawParachuter4() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 4
        x = 170;
        y = 150;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter5();
    }

    private void drawParachuter5() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 5
        x = 180;
        y = 170;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter6();
    }

    private void drawParachuter6() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 6
        x = 200;
        y = 180;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
    }

    public void drawParachuters()
    {
            Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
            parachuters.add(p);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "x=" + x + " y=" + y, 15).show();
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean bRun)
    {
        running = bRun;
    }

    public boolean getRunning()
    {
        return running;
    }
}

/** Handle to the application context, used to e.g. fetch Drawables. */
private Context mContext;

/** Pointer to the text view to display "Paused.." etc. */
private TextView mStatusText;

/** The thread that actually draws the animation */
private ExampleThread eThread;

public ExampleView(Context context)
{
    super(context);

    // register our interest in hearing about changes to our surface
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);

    // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
    eThread = new ExampleThread(holder, context, new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message m)
        {
           // mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
           // mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
        }
    });

    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    return eThread.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public ExampleThread getThread()
{
    return eThread;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    if (eThread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED)
    {
        eThread = new ExampleThread(getHolder(), getContext(), getHandler());
        eThread.start();
    }
    else
    {
        eThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    boolean retry = true;
    eThread.setRunning(false);

    while (retry)
    {
        try
        {
            eThread.join();
            retry = false;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try using the `equals()` method something like this `if (livesLeftValue.equals(3))` and you need to include some additional portion in your code snippet.

Comment: @Lion, that shouldn't be necessary for `int` comparisons.  But yeah, I am assuming livesleftValue is an `int`.. @OP is it possible `livesLeftValue` is higher than 3?  Maybe it started/gets higher than 3 so this method is "missed".  Or, as @Lion points out, can you post some more code?  Like where is livesLeftValue declared and where else is it used?

Comment: your variable might be reset ( set with another value ) in some other methods? please paste complete code. or you might use Integer instead of int. if you realy want help, share more information!

Comment: livesLeftValue starts with 0 and should be 3 after the third `doDraw()` - I don't see any reason why that would not happen. Maybe it comes too early and you don't see the Toast that should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others, check the value via Log messages, so you can see the actual values.

Also, check if it might go over 3. I dont know what kind of game you are making but for example, say that livesLeftValue=2 for now, but something happens, and it increases by 2, reaching 4, without ever having the value 3. Lets say it never gets decreased, so you will never ever hit the value 3, thus never invoking the game over thingie, and livesLeftValue will just increase to the infinity.

Answer (score 0):

put some debug in there and see if you really get the right value in here.

```
private void checkLivesLeftValue() {
    Log.d("checkLivesLeftValue", "lives = " + livesLeftValue);
    if (livesLeftValue == 3) {
        Log.d("checkLivesLeftValue", "calling onMethod now");
        onMethod();
    } else {
        livesLeftValue = livesLeftValue + 1;
        Log.d("checkLivesLeftValue", "increased lives to " + livesLeftValue);
    }
}

public void onMethod() {
    Log.d("onMethod", "in onMethod");
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("onMethod", "showing Toast now");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You lost!", 15).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I did that, and it workes just like planned: value: 0, increased to 1, value 1, increased to 2, value 2, increased to 3, value 3, calling onMethod now